# Making point predictions using Cox proportional hazard

Tags: python, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I am using the `pysurvival` library to model with the Cox proportional hazard model (CPH). Instead of getting the survival curves, I am interested in getting point predictions. In the library, the function `predict_survival` returns an *array-like representing the prediction of the survival function* which I assume that I can use to get the expected values - but I just cant find the right way.

Below I've attached a dummy example.

```
# Initializing the simulation model
sim = SimulationModel( survival_distribution = 'log-logistic',
                       risk_type = 'linear',
                       censored_parameter = 10.1,
                       alpha = 0.1, beta=3.2 )
# Generating N random samples 
N = 200
dataset = sim.generate_data(num_samples = N, num_features = 4)
# Defining the features
features = sim.features
# Creating the X, T and E input
X, T, E = dataset[features], dataset['time'].values, dataset['event'].values
# Building the model
coxph = CoxPHModel()
coxph.fit(X,T,E, lr=0.5, l2_reg=1e-2, init_method='zeros')
```

When applying the function:

```
coxph.predict_survival(x=X)
```

It returns an array of arrays with the shape `(200, 87)` - why does it give exactly 87 values for every observation?

As far as I understand I should be able to get the expected value by taking the integral below the curve of the survival curve.

[image]

To do this I need to calculate the area under the curve which I think can be done using `trapz` in the `numpy` library, but I need to know how the spacing between the points are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned we can use the function `predict_survival` to get the estimated survival probability. Furthermore, by calling `coxPH.times` we obtain the time of every estimated survival probability, and thereby for example can plot the individual survival curve for every observation and calculate the area under the curve. By using the `auc` function from the `sklearn.metrics` library the following definition gives point predictions for the training and test set given a CPH model, the `X_test` data and `X_train` data:

```
## Get point predictions
def point_pred(model, X_test, X_train):
    T_pred = []
    T_pred_train = []
    # Get survival curves
    cph_pred = model.predict_survival(X_test)
    cph_pred_train = model.predict_survival(X_train)
    # get times of survival prediction
    time = model.times
    # test
    for i in range(0,len(cph_pred)):
        T_pred.append(auc(time,cph_pred[i]))
    # train
    for i in range(0,len(cph_pred_train)):
        T_pred_train.append(auc(time,cph_pred_train[i]))
    
    return T_pred, T_pred_train
```